# How to create mirror effect on cursor on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to create a mirroring effect with the cursor on a webpage (using Javascript perhaps?). Take for example in the code below, the line between the black and white portion of the page would be the "line of reflection," so if the mouse were moving around in the top black portion, there would be an inverse image of a cursor and inverse action happening in the the bottom white portion, and vice versa.

Any help and pointers (no pun intended) on where to start would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:** I tried using .mousemove(), event.pageX, event.pageY as people suggested (shown below). I'm pretty new to Javascript so I have issues making it work.

**cursor.html**

```
<doctype! html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="cursor.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="cursor.js"></script>
        <title> Cursor Mirror </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="top-half-black"></div>
        <div class="bottom-half-white">     
                <img id="mirror-image" src="upside-down.png">
        </div>

    <script>

    $(".top-half-black").mousemove(function(event){
        var xPosition = event.pageX;
        var yPosition = event.pageY;
    })


    function placeCursor() {
        var d = document.getElementById('mirror-image');
        d.style.position = "absolute";
        d.style.left = xPosition+'px';
        d.style.top = -yPosition+'px';
    }

    $( ".top-half-black").mouseover(function( event ){
        placeCursor () ;
    })



    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**cursor.css**

```
body{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.top-half-black{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
```

**What I want it to look like:**

[image]

Comment: Thinking out loud. You could grab the cursor position in the top div on mouse move events. You could have a canvas element in the bottom div and calculate a cursor position for that based on the cursor position in the top div. You'd need to update the canvas on mouse move events in the top div.

Comment: You could implement this pretty easily using an absolutely positioned image of the mouse cursor and jquery's `mousemove()` event and `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` properties.

Comment: Yeahhh don't use a canvas, will be more work than is necessary. Absolute positioning of a cursor image element will handle it.

Comment: @leemo Thanks I will try that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine you want something like this.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="section top-half-black"></div>
<div class="section bottom-half-white">
  <img id="mirror-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/cjjNbk1.png"></img>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.top-half-black{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}

.bottom-half-white{
  position: relative;
}

#mirror-image{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 25px;
}

.section{
  display: block;
  min-height: 10em;
}
```

#### JS:

```
var $img = $('#mirror-image');
var imgHeight = $img.height() / 2;
function placeCursor(x, y){
  $img.css({top: y + 'px', left: x+ 'px', position:'absolute'});
}

$(".top-half-black").mousemove(function(event){
  var newY = $(this).height() - event.pageY - imgHeight;
  placeCursor(event.pageX, newY);
});
```

Working demo:
http://codepen.io/alirezanoori/pen/YyagKP

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for! If I wanted to make it invert the other way when I hover over the bottom white version, would I make another event handler for .bottom-half-white? But I would also have to hide  the image of the cursor in the bottom half as well...

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I would suggest. I think you'll be able to do it yourself. Let me know if you had any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about changing colors but if you can find some images of the cursor colors you want you can add this to your CSS classes.

```
 cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png), auto;
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change my cursor. Read the question more carefully.

Comment: I'm saying if you find a pic of a inversed cursors you can use those for each div. Kind of a workaround.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm trying to create a mirrored image of the cursor, not trying to change its color.

Comment: Ok I mean yeah, but I'd still have to use jquery since the mirrored cursor would have to move around at the same time as the actual cursor. And I probably would have it as an image, not as part of the css right?

Comment: Yes I changed my comment. See the images you have above. If you can find some of just the cursors, or crop those images you can use those and get the same effect.

Comment: I don't believe you do.