# How to make div disappear when image is placed over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseover

In a previous question, I asked how to make a "cursor mirror," meaning if your cursor were to move around in the top portion of a site, a separate inversed image of a cursor would move in the inverse direction in the bottom portion of a site. Link to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337089/how-to-create-mirror-effect-on-cursor-on-a-web-page).

Continuing with this code, if the actual cursor in the top half hovered over a div to make it disappear (using CSS hover states), how would the mirror-image cursor achieve the same effect using Javascript without using the .mouseover event (since it's not mouse but a placed image)? Sorry if the title is vague, but the problem is hard to describe!

```js
var $img = $('#mirror-image');
var imgHeight = $img.height() / 2;
function placeCursor(x, y){
  $img.css({top: y + 'px', left: x+ 'px', position:'absolute'});
}

$(".top-half-black").mousemove(function(event){
  var newY = $(this).height() - event.pageY - imgHeight;
  placeCursor(event.pageX, newY);
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.top-half-black{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}

.bottom-half-white{
  position: relative;
}

#mirror-image{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 25px;
}

.rightside-up{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:36px;
    color:white;
}

.rightside-up:hover{
   opacity:0;
}

.upside-down{
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:36px;

  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
     -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
       -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
          transform: scaleY(-1); 
}
```

```html
<div class="top-half-black">
   <div class="rightside-up">Blah blah blah</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-half-white">
  <img id="mirror-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/cjjNbk1.png" />
   <div class="upside-down"> Blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
        function hideDiv() {
            $(".upside-down").hide();
        }

        function showDiv() {
            $(".upside-down").show();
        }

        $(".rightside-up").hover(hideDiv, showDiv);
```

Comment: I'd prefer to have the opacity set to 0 than to hide it?

Comment: Perhaps by adding/removing classes?

Comment: i think this method will perform much better than detecting the mirrored mouse image over some element. - but it isnt that generic, because you need to know the elements by name.

Comment: add/remove classes should be the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the [adjacent sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to allow you to control the style of `.upside-down` when hovering over `top-half-black`. E.G:

```
.top-half-black:hover .rightside-up,
.top-half-black:hover ~ .bottom-half-white .upside-down {
     opacity:0
}
```

```js
var $img = $('#mirror-image');
var imgHeight = $img.height() / 2;
function placeCursor(x, y){
  $img.css({top: y + 'px', left: x+ 'px', position:'absolute'});
}

$(".top-half-black").mousemove(function(event){
  var newY = $(this).height() - event.pageY - imgHeight;
  placeCursor(event.pageX, newY);
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.top-half-black{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}

.bottom-half-white{
  position: relative;
}

#mirror-image{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 25px;
}

.rightside-up{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:36px;
    color:white;
}

/*.rightside-up:hover{
   opacity:0;
}*/
.top-half-black:hover .rightside-up,
.top-half-black:hover ~ .bottom-half-white .upside-down {
  opacity:0
}

.upside-down{
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:36px;

  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
     -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
       -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
          transform: scaleY(-1); 
}
```

```html
<div class="top-half-black">
   <div class="rightside-up">Blah blah blah</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-half-white">
  <img id="mirror-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/cjjNbk1.png" />
   <div class="upside-down"> Blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE...**

Further to your comment, you could use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` to find the element *under* the mirrored cursor image and toggle its class name:

```js
var $img = $('#mirror-image');
var imgHeight = $img.height() / 2;
function placeCursor(x, y){
  $img.css({top: y + 'px', left: x+ 'px', position:'absolute'});
}

$(".top-half-black").mousemove(function(event){
  var newY = $(this).height() - event.pageY - imgHeight;
  var x = event.pageX,
      y =  $(this).height() + event.pageY;
  $(".upside-down .hovered").removeClass("hovered");
  placeCursor(x, newY);
  var mirrorEl = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
  $(mirrorEl).addClass("hovered");
});
```

```css
body{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.top-half-black{
    background-color:black;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}

.bottom-half-white{
  position: relative;
}

#mirror-image{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 17px;
  height: 25px;
}

.rightside-up{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:36px;
    color:white;
}

.rightside-up span:hover{
   opacity:0;
}

.upside-down span.hovered{
   opacity:0;
}

.upside-down{
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:36px;

  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
     -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(-1);
       -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
          transform: scaleY(-1); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-half-black">
   <div class="rightside-up"><span>Blah</span> <span>blah</span> <span>blah</span></div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-half-white">
  <img id="mirror-image" src="http://i.imgur.com/cjjNbk1.png" />
   <div class="upside-down"><span>Blah</span> <span>blah</span> <span>blah</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks this is helpful and totally works but I'm not sure how to write this method with something more specific within the div since this is ideally supposed to help me with my nav bar. For example, if only the first word "Blah" in "Blah blah blah" had a Id attached to it, how would I write the style to make the upside down "Blah" disappear (which would also have its own Id) when I hover over "Blah"?

Comment: You could use `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)` to find the element under the mirrored cursor. See my updated answer.

Comment: is document.elementFromPoint(x,y) supported in mobile browsers? the mdn compatibility table leaves question marks here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onmousemove` event on the whole document, and then check if the inverse cursor is over the element in question. Lets say you want to simulate a mouse move event for the inverse cursor over an element with ID `hover`.

```
//Save a reference to the element for speed.
var hover = $("#hover");

//When the mouse moves anywhere.
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    //I assume you have the position of the inverse cursor in variables x and y.
    //I guesse the solution to your previous question should give you that. 
    //Save the distance between the inverse cursor and the top left corner of #hover.
    var diffX = hover.offset().left - x;
    var diffY = hover.offset().top - y;
    //Check if the shadow cursor is inside #hover.
    if(diffX >= 0 && diffX <= hover.width() && diffY >= 0 && diffY <= hover.height()) {
        //Things here will run if the inverse curser is inside hover.
    }
    else {
        //Thigs here will run if the inverse cursor is not inside hover.
    }
}
```

The code would be neater if you could use [`.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint), but Mozilla advises against using it as it is "experimental technology".